# How to filter Excel data before loading to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to load only users who their status are `"Disabled"` in `Status` column into Pandas data frame. My initial code is like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Users.XLSX', sheet_name='WebUsers',  usecols="A,B")
print(df)
```

Which is bringing all users no matter they are "Disabled" or "Active". How can I add a filter like `WHERE 'Status' == 'Disabled'` and load only disabled users into frame?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible (only) with Pandas. `pd.read_excel(...).query("Status == 'disabled'")[['A', 'B']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with Pandas, you have to filter **after** Pandas loads the file:

```
df = (pd.read_excel('Users.XLSX', sheet_name='WebUsers', usecols=['A', 'B', 'Status'])
        .query("Status == 'disabled'").drop(columns='Status'))
```

Note: `parquet` is a column-oriented data file format so you can filter your dataframe before.

Answer (score 1):

For most data Pandas is the quick solution but if data is very large and cannot read all data into memory then you could use [Polars](https://realpython.com/polars-python/) to load and filter the data in one shot. Polars is 10 to 100 times faster than Pandas so is a good alternative.

To install will need polars and the supporting xlsx package:

`pip install polars xlsx2csv`

```python
import polars as pl

# this is a reference to the data source and doesn't load the data into memory
lazy_data = pl.read_excel('Users.XLSX', sheet_name='WebUsers')

df = (
     lazy_data
     .filter(
         pl.col("Status") == "Disabled"
     )
     .drop("Status")
)
print(df)
```

If want to move the data frame into Pandas can use the `to_pandas()` function on the result to create a Pandas data frame from it.